# Опредлить тип речи.

Tags: синтаксис

Надлежало начинать Лермонтову, он выстрелил в воздух, желая кончить глупую эту ссору
дружелюбно. ***Мартынов был довольно бесчеловечен и злобен***, чтобы подойти к самому
противнику своему и выстрелить ему прямо в сердце. Удар был так силен и верен, что смерть
была столь же скоропостижной, как выстрел. Несчастный Лермонтов испустил дух.
Мартынов поступил против всех правил чести, благородства и справедливости. Ежели бы он
хотел, чтобы дуэль совершилась, ему следовало сказать Лермонтову: «Извольте зарядить
опять ваш пистолет. Я вам советую хорошенько в меня целиться, ибо я буду стараться вас
убить». Так поступил бы благородный, храбрый офицер. Мартынов поступил как убийца.

***1. повествование с элементами описания   2 повествование с  элементами рассуждения 3 рассуждие с элементами повествования.***

В первом повествуется о том, что надлежало сделать Лермонтову, о том, что он сделал. Но в нем есть и описание (выделено жирным). 
 Во втором тексте автор раасуждает, как поступил Мартынов.

Т.е. здесь представлены все три типа, а надо выбрать два. Может, здесь ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в первой части мы имеем **повествование с элементами рассуждения**, так как фраза "Мартынов был довольно бесчеловечен и злобен" ― это оценочное рассуждение, а не описание.

Во второй части дается **рассуждение с элементами повествования**, при этом повествование представлено как возможный вариант развития событий.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, вы правы. В голову не пришло.